# IF Column AJ contains "Customer" then Apply Filter in B:B Else In VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a small script in VBA. Say I have the data in Excel worksheet (`sheet1`) and want to apply filter on certain condition. If column `AJ:AJ` contains the word "CUSTOMER", then apply filter range `B:B` or `Else Msgbox("Customer NA")`. I am currently using the code below, but it is making the Excel freeze. Any help really appreciated.

```
Sub test()
    For i = 1 To 1048576
        Range("AJ" & i).Select
        ss = Len(ActiveCell.Value)
        For j = 1 To ss
            dd = StrConv(Mid(ActiveCell.Value, j, 8), vbProperCase)
            If dd = "Customer" Then
                check = 1
                check = 0
                Range("AJ1").Activate
                Selection.AutoFilter
                Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
                Range("AJ1").Select
                ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AQ$37518").AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:= _
                    "=*Customer*", Operator:=xlAnd
                Exit For
                check = 0
            Else
            End If
        Next j
        If check = 1 Then
            Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code freezing? Have you stepped through the code using `Breakpoints` and `F8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is freezing excel because you are doing the comparison about as inefficiently as possible :) by looping over *every* row (1048576) and then every character in every cell in that row.

Instead, try using the range `.Find` method:

```
Sub testFind()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngFound As Range

Set rng = Range("AJ:AJ")

Set rngFound = rng.Find("CUSTOMER")

If rngFound Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Customer N/A"
Else:
    'Apply your filter here

End If


End Sub
```